# Sum according to dates in a single query in PostgreSql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, date, sum

I have a table like below:

```
ID | Date       | Value
---+------------+------
H1 | 11/9/2015  | 3
H2 | 11/10/2015 | 5
H3 | 11/11/2015 | 2
H1 | 11/9/2015  | 1
H2 | 11/13/2015 | 4
H3 | 11/8/2015  | 5
H1 | 11/15/2015 | 8
```

I want to create a single query which can show me the result as below:

```
ID | All Values | Future Values
---+------------+--------------
H1 |         12 |             8
H2 |          9 |             9
H3 |          7 |             2
```

I am able to sum all the data by writing query

```
select ID, Sum(ID) from table group by ID
```

but how to sum future data in same query? I managed to create a separate query for future data:

```
select ID, sum(ID) from table where date > now() group by ID
```

Please help me out to make a single query... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CASE WHEN:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  SUM(value) AS all_values,
  SUM(CASE WHEN date > current_date THEN value END) AS future_values
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  ID
```

(I'm using current_date because I think that your date column contains just date information with no time, use now() if this is not the case)